# How to change excel formulae of xlsx to be compatible with xls with least effort?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xls, xlsx, backwards-compatibility

I have prepared an excel workbook in latest version saved as .xlsx
I need it to run on an older PC using an older excel (.xls)
Some of the **compatibility issues** it reports deal with:

1. Table References
2. COUNTIFS
3. IFNA
4. Conditional formatting

There are many places where I need to change these formulae. If left as is, I get #NAME error. Is there a way to lessen the effort of going to each formula and replacing with older formulae?

Also, what can be used instead of COUNTIFS? It was pretty essential to my excel.

Any help/redirection will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes. Upgrade the Excel on the older computer. There are views available for viewing xlsx files in older versions of xlsx, or online versions (office 365)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid that is not in my hands. I need to give something that by itself works on the older excel version. I would have no control over how it is used once it is submitted

Comment: There is no automatic method.  If you cannot upgrade the excel version, you will need to visit every formula.  And for `COUNTIFS` there are plenty of examples of using `SUMPRODUCT`

Comment: I think @RonRosenfeld is right, I had to change many of my functions to suite .xls . Lesson learnt, check which version your code is going to run on. If in future one does get a way to convert, please let us know